# How to get the clicked button in notification.confirm() in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have used the Phonegap notification.confirm as like below,

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Do you want to continue ?',
     function() {
         console.log("Called");
     },
    'Game Over',
    'Continue,Exit'
);
```

How can i trace the clicked button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user clicks any button, you callback function is triggered with the index of the button.
You can get to check the index and proceed as per your requirement.

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Do you want to continue ?',
    function(btnIndex) {
        if(!btnIndex)
            console.log("Continue");
        else
            console.log("Exit");
    },
    'Game Over',
    'Continue,Exit'
);
```

The value for `btnIndex` will be `0 - Continue`, `1 - Exit`. This index is totally based on the sequence you have provided in `navigator.notification.confirm`.

Hope this helps you.